# Flutter I want to put checkbox on each item

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I want to set a checkbox for each item while pulling DB data with Flutter, but in the current code like this, clicking the checkbox will check all the items.
I tried removing the checkbox from the list, but it didn't work.

It is assumed that the DB data is already included.
Please tell me how to resolve.

```
class Classname extends StatefulWidget {
  Classname({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _ClassnameState();
}

class _ClassnameState extends State<Classname> {
  String test;
  String test2;
  String test3;
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Map>> getData() async {
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'dbname.db');

    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tablename(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT)");
    });

    List<Map> result = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tablename');
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, result) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(                
                child: Column(                    
                    children: List.generate(result.data.length, (index) {
                      var data = result.data[index];
                      test = data['test'];
                      test2 = data['test2'];
                      test3 = data['test3'];
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(                            
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Checkbox(
                                value: isChecked,
                                onChanged: (bool value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isChecked = value;
                                  });
                                },                               
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  test,
                                ),
                              ),                              
                              Container(
                                child: Text(test2),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,                            
                              child: Text(
                                test3,                                
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
      ),
    );
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are assigning same variable to all of your checkboxes. So, all of your checkboxes are showing the same value. You have to create as many variables as there are checkboxes. Better implementation would be the data that is used to generate the list should also contain a field for checkbox state. I have added the field to the data. Check the following code.

```
class Classname extends StatefulWidget {
  Classname({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _ClassnameState();
}

class _ClassnameState extends State<Classname> {
  String test;
  String test2;
  String test3;
  bool isChecked = false;
  Future _data;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _data = getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Map>> getData() async {
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'dbname.db');

    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tablename(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT)");
    });

    List<Map> result = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tablename');
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
        future: _data,
        builder: (context, result) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: List.generate(result.data.length, (index) {
                  var data = result.data[index];
                  test = data['test'];
                  test2 = data['test2'];
                  test3 = data['test3'];
                  data.putIfAbsent('isChecked', () => false);
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Checkbox(
                            value: data['isChecked'],
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                data['isChecked'] = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              test,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(test2),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          test3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood the structure. I tried it and no Dart Analysis error on Android Studio but Simulator displayed an error screen. Error message is 'Unsupported operation: read-only'. I checked many times for typographical errors but no problem. I would appreciate it if you could tell me what was wrong.